# How to calculate optimal bend angle for moving monowheel vehicle?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, speed

Imagine you are driving a monowheel vehicle (https://www.google.com/search?q=monowheel) at some speed ***S*** (km/h) and you need to take a curve, so you steer by angle ***A*** in the respective direction, BUT to not fall over and crash you actually need to bend the whole thing (it's same for motorcycles and bikes) for some ***B*** angle.

So given speed ***S***, steer angle ***A***, tire size (radius ***R***) and position of mass center ***C***, can I calculate the optimum bend angle ***B*** that makes the vehicle successfully make the curve (not fall over)? And the threshold where no bending (not matter how much) would help to not to crash?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an ideal curve, (an arc of a circle), then the horizontal force (static friction from the road must supply the centripetal acceleration, and the normal force must support the weight. For stability, the resultant should be directed through the center of mass.

Comment: Makes sense. I am thinking How do I put this ideas in united formula?

Answer (score 1):

you can use those equations:

$$\tan(\alpha)=\frac{m\,v^2/r}{m\,g}=\frac{v^2}{r\,g}$$

with a "single track model"

$$\frac{1}{r}\approx\frac{\delta}{L}$$

thus
$$\tan(\alpha)=\frac{v^2}{L\,g}\,\delta$$

where

- $v~$ vehicle speed
- $r~$ curve radius
- $\delta~$ steer angle
- $m~$ vehicle mass
- $~L$  wheel base
- $~\alpha$ bend angle

Comment: And what is `g` ? `L` is space between wheels? In my case it's *0*? :)

Comment: I guess by now `g` is gravity constant?

Comment: this is correct, but what is your wheel base, because, you just have one wheel?

Comment: yes monowheel vehicle has one wheel. So I have no idea how to represent the wheel base.

Comment: you can take some “fictive” wheel base

Comment: can you please edit your post with and example calculation assuming wheelbase is 0.1, speed is 100km/h and steer angle is 45?Pls! Because for me the numbers end up not good.

Comment: your radius r is 0,12 m, so you go straight line. check first the equations with bicycle

Comment: r = curve radius ? Its a dynamic property in simulation? Its better to calc with steer angle.

Comment: if you drive your bike with 20 km/h in a curve with radius 20 m , your bend angle , from the first equation is 8.5 degree, which is realistic, snd the steer angle is approximately 4 degree, wheel base 1.5 m

Comment: Yes but I do not have a bike or a real wheel base (as it is 1 wheel vehicle). Neither I know the curve radius. So the question is not answered :/