# Is it possible to calculate bike needed leaning angle from steering angle?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, speed, centripetal-force

For a bike steering with radius of curvature $r$, we have
$$\theta = \arctan \frac{v^2}{gr}$$
but you need to know *r*. I want to calculate the leaning angle from steering angle. It should be just enough so the bike doesn't fall over. Is it possible?

**Edit:**

Forget to mention that I also want to calculate same thing for monowheel bikes.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/650524/how-to-calculate-optimal-bend-angle-for-moving-monowheel-vehicle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, by "steering angle" you mean the angle $\alpha$
between the front wheel and the rest of the bicycle
as shown in this top view of a curving bicycle.
[image: top view of a curving bicycle]
From the right triangle you can derive the equation
$$\tan\alpha = \frac{L}{r}$$
where $L$ is the distance between front wheel and back wheel,
and $r$ is the radius of the curve driven by the back wheel.
Together with the other equation already given in your question
$$\tan\theta=\frac{v^2}{gr}$$
you can eliminate the radius $r$ and find

$$\tan\theta = \frac{v^2}{gL}\tan\alpha$$

Comment: Thomas what if it's a monowheel bike? Like L is then 0 and formula is screwed up?

Comment: @JohnT How would you even define the steering angle for a monowheel bike?

Comment: @Thomas btw i tried you formula with 80km/h, wheel base 1m and steer angle 15. It ended up with 90+ degrees for leaning that can't be right. Or can?

Comment: @Eli how? Can you show your calculations?

Comment: The 8000 should be 80,000 and then $\tan\theta$ is 13.5 and $\theta$ is 85.8 degrees (with g=9.8)

Comment: So the leaning angle is almost 90 degrees what sounds wrong at this speed and steer. Just as i said before.

Comment: @trshmanx Your steering angle $\alpha=15°$ is very large. So you get a very small curve radius $r=L/\tan\alpha=3.7$ m. Driving this tight curve with high speed $v=80$ km/h is insane. So it is no surprise you got an insane leaning angle of nearly $90°$.

Comment: again \begin{aligned}\dfrac{\left( \dfrac{80000}{3600}\right) ^{2}}{10}\times \tan \left( 15\right) \simeq 13.232\\
\theta \simeq \arctan \left( 13\right) \simeq 85.601\\
r\simeq \left( \tan \left( 15\right) \right) ^{-1}\simeq 3.732\end{aligned}

Comment: @ThomasFritsch created a small script that runs the formula. https://jsfiddle.net/rcpsgf3y/1/ . With 60 km/h and 5 degrees 68 lean angle. Maybe it's right?

Answer (score 1):

For a monowheel bike there is only leaning angle, steering angle is undefined.

Leaning at an angle $\theta$ will cause the monowheel bike to move in a circle of radius $$r=\frac{v^2}{g\tan\theta}$$

Comment: Not sure your claim is right. I just tried it with a real wheel and it doesn't go in curve just from leaning.

Comment: @ trshmanx was your wheel also travelling at velocity $v$?

Comment: Kind of. I am confused.

Comment: @ trshmanx the diagrams on the top right of this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_and_motorcycle_dynamics show leaning causing the turn of a bike

Comment: I just ride a bike. Leaning it causes me to steer at same direction to not to fall. So steering still happens becouse of my hand force and not just becouse of leaning.

Comment: Not sure also how to interp. the results. With speed 60 km/h and lean angle 30 I get r = 45. Its kind of to big?